# Accesing, Merging IIS extended log files

Tags: asp.net, iis, logging

I need to access, merge and parse my log files using my asp.net application programmatically. I use shared hosting and as I can see log files are out of the root directory of my website? Is there anyway to access those files from my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, as long as you set permission to the log directory with the files for your asp.net running user.

Get your application path:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
```

and manipulate to your log directory file...